# Weight transfer proof of Turán’s theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, probability-distributions, extremal-graph-theory, optimal-transportation, extremal-combinatorics

*Turán’s theorem*, which states that a $K_{p+1}$-free graph contains at most $(1-1/p)\frac{N^2}{2}$ edges, can be proven in many different ways, as pointed out, for example in *M. Aigner, G. M. Ziegler, [Proofs from THE BOOK](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-57265-8)*. One of the proofs (3rd) looks in the following way:

—— The recapitulation of the proof ——

**Step 1.** Squeeze $w$ to a clique.

1. Introduce some weights $w_i$ to the vertices, such that $w_i\geq 0$ and $\sum w_i=1$, so it can be also considered as a *probability distribution* $\mathbf{w}$. Then, the aim is to maximise the *Lagrangian* (see discussion below) $$f(\mathbf{w}) = \sum\limits_{v_iv_j\in E} w_iw_j$$
2. Introduce some notion of *weight transfer* (actually, we take two non-connected vertices and *transfer* weight from the vertex with small weight to another vertex with large weight). It turns out that after this operation, the *Lagrangian* increases.
3. Repeat this procedure and note that $w$ is concentrated on a clique when we cannot do an operation.

**Step 2.** Equidistribution on the clique.

1. Consider two vertices in the clique of distinct weights: $(v_i,w_i^\ast)$ and $(v_j,w_j^\ast)$ where $w^\ast$ is the resulting distribution from step 1. Then we perform another weight transfer: $(v_i,w_i^\ast-\varepsilon)$ and $(v_j,w_j^\ast+\varepsilon)$ assuming $w_i^\ast>w_j^\ast>0$ and $0<\varepsilon<w_i^\ast-w_j^\ast$.
2. It is straightforward to prove that $f$ increases. As in step 1, we repeat this *weight transfer*. When we cannot continue this procedure, it means that we have no vertices with distinct weights, thus $w_i = 1/k$, if $i$ is in $k$-clique and $0$ otherwise.

**Step 3.** Estimate for equidistribution.

1. Estimate what the value of $f(w^{\ast\ast})$ where $w^{\ast\ast}$ is the equidistribution from step 2 assuming we are $K_{p+1}$-free.
2. Just finish the proof.

This method originated from *T. S. Motzkin, E. G. Straus, [Maxima for Graphs and a New Proof of a Theorem of Turán](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1965-053-6)*. But sometimes, as one can see from Master’s thesis *Lagrangians of Hypergraphs* by *A. Caraceni*, it is sometimes called *Lagrangians*.

—— Questions ——

My questions are:

1. What is the motivation to call them *Lagrangians*? Specifically, I do not see a connection between Lagrangians in field theory and these ones.
2. What are other manifestations of the described approach? Specifically, introducing some weights and a target function and doing some transfers to optimise this value.

Comment: I haven’t looked into the literature carefully, but the earliest reference I can find so far that uses such terminology is Peter Frankl and Vojtěch Rödl, “Hypergraphs do not jump”, *Combinatorica* **4** (1984), 149–159. Specifically, they introduce “Lagrange functions of hypergraphs”. They motivate the choice of terminology implicitly by the use of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now. For some reason, I forgot that Lagrangian is an alternative name to the Lagrange function in the Lagrange multipliers :)